# Changing handedness coordinate system between unity and opencv

Tags: unity

[image: Problem explanation]
For my problem given System A, opencv and unity.
I have the

1. Inversed extrinsic parameters in the "System A convertion".
2. Intrinsic parameters (Can form into projectionMatrix) in the "Opencv convention".

***My first question is***
When I'm doing the projection. Do i need to convert a convention to have the same direction as opencv then I do the projection. Or I can do it directly without any negated axis?. The step you can see below.

===========================================================================

[image: Problem 2 explanation]

I want to set the camera from System A into the unity. What I did is following the image.

1. I rearrange the axis from System A to be the same as Unity. (Rotating + Negated the sign)
2. Once it had the same convention to the unity.I took the rotation matrix and use the scipy.transform.as_euler(R, order='zxy'). Then negated the sign the get the angle for left-handed.
3. Rotation into Euler angles by using scipy.transfrom.as_euler (order of 'zxy' following unity document). Since the scipy accept the right-handed coordinate system. Then i will got an angle of rotation. Then negated the axis.
4. Translation : I don't know that this should got negated the direction of an axis

***My second question is***
I think my procedure is wrong. Since the scipy libs accept the right-handed system. So I don't know that how to find the euler rotation angle from given rotation matrix in the right-handed system and change it into the left-handed system.

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Puntawat Ponglertnapakorn

Comment: Don't forget to negate each rotation angle since positive rotations spin in opposite directions in left-handed and right-handed coordinates. If you run into trouble, please edit your question to include a full description/diagram of your initial and destination coordinate systems (don't assume every reader who can help you knows what coordinate system OpenCV uses), the code you're currently using to perform the conversion, and a test case that demonstrates a mismatch between that code's output and your expected output. With that in hand, we can help you debug the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I have to negated the sign with i'm not sure the way to find euler angles are correct. Should i get the eulre angles from scipy first and the negated the sign of rotation matrix after to match the left-handed system